# jQuery single page mobile app

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am trying to build a jQuery app with multiple page. Where different pages are placed in different html files.
**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Dynamic Page Example</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <sciprt src="abc.js"></sciprt>
        <div data-role="page" id="home" data-title="Welcome">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Dynamic Page</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <input type=button id="changePage" value="Open dynamic page">
                <!--<a href="abc.html" data-prefetch>abc</a>-->
            </div>
            <script>
                $("#changePage").on("click", function() {
                    // Create page markup


                    // Enhance and open new page

                    $.mobile.changePage('abc.html');

                });
            </script>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

**abc.html**

```
<div data-role=page data-url=hi id=abc>
    <div data-role=header id=first>
        <h1>
           <script>
            document.write(msg.first);</script>
        </h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role=content id=second>

           <script>
            document.write(msg.second);</script>
    </div>
</div>
```

**abc.js**

```
var msg = {
    first : 'I am First',
    second : 'I am Second',
    third : 'I am Third'

};
```

I don't understand where i am doing wrong.When there is no javascript im abc.html then it works, but when i try to use js, it just shows loading.

Any help would be great....

Comment: in your abc html, did you define the html before the var msg? If so, simply put the script which defines msg before the html markup. You have inline script (which is always bad) which requires this variable to be initialized...

Comment: i think its a problem with jquery mobile https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/430 try using jquery append() to insert values into the div instead javascript

Comment: I didn't understand what are u saying. I want to load the abc.html in the same DOM.

Comment: i tried to use 
    `$('#first').append(msg.first);`
    `$('#second').append(msg.second);`
but getting error that `msg` is not defined. I am adding these lines in abc.html

Comment: `<sciprt src="abc.js"></sciprt>` – read again

Comment: @IngoBürk i tried that already but nothing gets append to div.

Comment: No, read your code again. You misspelled `script`, so your file never gets loaded. Which is why you get that `msg` is undefined.

Comment: thanks @IngoBürk. I had a typo mistake. but after that i don't know when to execute the above append statements, So that it will create an dynamic page....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all sorry because of the typo mistake i did at

```
<sciprt src="abc.js"></sciprt>
```

It should be (Thanks to @Ingo Burk for pointing it out)

```
<script src="abc.js"></script>
```

Secondly i tried to using

```
$('#second').append(msg.second);
$('#first').append(msg.first);
```

But didn't work out then i used

```
$('#second').html(msg.second);
$('#first').html(msg.first);
```

and that solved my problem.
And also don't use `document.write()` in a page, when u are loading page via `$.load()`. I wasted 3 days because of this(  thanks to @Ram for pointing it out). Check https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/430